# Scale up a fabric 2.2 network with many clients and servers

Tags: networking, hyperledger-fabric

I am using a Fabric 2.2 network with two organizations, one endorsing peer per organization and one ordering service.

I want to scale up my network with many clients and servers in order to test the performance of the system (latency and throughput), similarly to what it is done in this paper [ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel7/69/4358933/08246573.pdf](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel7/69/4358933/08246573.pdf) in section 6.1.2

I confuse maybe the terms. I am really new to Fabric.

What is the meaning of "clients" and "servers" in the paper? Are they ca-servers and ca-clients? In this case, how to configure a network with an increasing number of Fabric clients and servers?

Comment: Do you want to add new organizations and new peers or just add peers to existing organizations?  There's really no reason I can think of to add 50 peers to an individual organization, but if you want to do that it's quite simple.  The link you reference above is about adding new organization and peers.

Comment: Thanks @GariSingh for your response. The thing is I have a network with two organizations. I want to test whether the system scales when the size of the network and the workload increase. Thus, I want to begin with 4 peer nodes (2 peers per organization), then 8 peers nodes (4 peers per organization) , then 16 peer nodes, etc.
So, my question is, in Fabric 2.2, how can one add many peers to an organization at once?

Comment: There is no way around generating credentials for each peer other than reusing the same identity information for each peer.  And then you do have to call "JoinChannel" on each peer as well.

But I'll reiterate my point:  you are not really testing any type of scalability this way.  You can still only have policies which require two endorsements as you only have two orgs.  About the only things you *might* be testing would be number of peers connected to orderer nodes and maybe gossip within an organization (but this is really not realistic on any case).

Comment: @GariSingh I maybe did not explain myself well. I edited the title and the question. I hope this explains more what exactly I want to do.